# in solrImportScheduler why we need to define reBuildIndexBeginTime for delta imports?

Tags: search, solr

On wiki page http://code.google.com/p/solr-dataimport-scheduler/

```
params=/dataimport?command=delta-import&clean=false&commit=true
interval=1
```

and what is purpose of this line

```
reBuildIndexBeginTime=03:10:00
```

**if i comment out `reBuildIndexBeginTime=03:10:00` the index never runs for delta imports**.
what is reBuildIndexBeginTime=03:10:00 , why we use it for delta imports?

dataimport.properties file in my solr-multicore installation

```
#################################################
#                                               #
#       dataimport scheduler properties         #
#                                               #
#################################################

#  to sync or not to sync
#  1 - active; anything else - inactive
syncEnabled=1

#  which cores to schedule
#  in a multi-core environment you can decide which cores you want syncronized
#  leave empty or comment it out if using single-core deployment
syncCores=hkc-core

#  solr server name or IP address
#  [defaults to localhost if empty]
server=localhost

#  solr server port
#  [defaults to 80 if empty]
port=1666

#  application name/context
#  [defaults to current ServletContextListener's context (app) name]
webapp=solr-multicore

#  URL params [mandatory]
#  remainder of URL
params=/dataimport?command=delta-import&clean=false&commit=true

#  schedule interval
#  number of minutes between two runs
#  [defaults to 30 if empty]
interval=1

#reBuildIndexInterval=7200
#reBuildIndexParams=/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true
reBuildIndexBeginTime=00:00:00
```

Comment: Ignore those. Just use instructions posted in [DIH wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Scheduling). I added the link to this (someone else's) project so that you don't have to build jar yourself.

Comment: if i remove reBuildIndexBeginTime property it does not do the delta imports.

Comment: Can you post your whole dataimport.properties file here, please.

Comment: I have added dataimport file into my question.

Comment: The source is open so you can check out what those two properties are for. Sorry, I cannot help you without diving into the code, but it's fairly simple code. Those two properties were subsequently added by Liang Zhang (project author) and I never needed to go through that source. One of these days I'll open my own project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as I promised, [here](http://code.google.com/p/solr-data-import-scheduler) it is.
Clean Data Import Handler Scheduler compiled source.